# Persistent SwiftData in 'Library/Containers' Directory After App Uninstallation on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swift-data

I've encountered an issue where SwiftData remains in the /Users/(username)/Library/Containers/~ directory even after my app has been deleted.(other apps too) This behavior is not what I expected.

Has anyone else faced this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question to me, isn't this an issue with any app on macOS that doesn't have a dedicated installer/uninstaller app that stuff gets left behind in ~/Library/...?

Comment: This question also pertains to SwiftData. Is it Apple's intention to leave previous data on the local device even after an app is deleted?
If so, is there a programming method to erase this data? I'm also curious if such an approach is common, especially in relation to issues where problems persist for users who delete and then redownload an app (particularly concerning specific data-related issues).

Thanks for comment.

Comment: It's not about Apple's intentions, this is your decision and responsibility how to handle app data and settings that are stored on disk. It's a major difference between a Mac computer and an iOS device so you shouldn't expect the OS to do as much on a Mac as iOS do when handling apps and app data.